# display image file from json

Tags: json, jsp

Hi i am sending this json  to jsp which contain file url i want to display image by     this url in ajax. can any one help me.

```
 //controller
  recordingInfo = recordingManager.getRecordingInfo(new Integer(recordingId));    

 map.put("status", true);    

 map.put("recordingInfo", recordingInfo);  

 return JSONSerializer.toJSON(map).toString();
```

Here i am sending json object to jsp and trying to get by ajax call as follows. this json contains url like

```
  d:/abc/xyz.jpg
```

i want to display it as image when i clicked on that url. how can i do that.

```
//jsp

 function showUploadedImages(recordingId) {
    $("#recordingId").val(recordingId);
    $("#newRecording").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'adminShowUploadedImages',
        data : ({
            recordingId : recordingId
        }),
        success : function(data) {
            var returnData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if (returnData.status) {
                alert(returnData);
        });
```

in returnData i have url i want to display it as image. help me

Comment: What is your question or problem? We can't help you if you don't tell us what you need help with...

Comment: what is the content of returnData paste it and will try to display as image first post the content

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103659/parse-image-from-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put a div in a body with attribute id picture e.g. `<div id="picture"></div>`
2. append img tag to the div

example

```
//code
success : function(data) {
      var returnData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);           
      $("#picture").append("<img src=\" + returnData.img_url + "\" />");
});
//code if any
```

Comment: ThanQ so much i am able to do now